# Display exact Requirement IDs using dxl in Doors

Tags: ibm-doors

i am parsing a requirement Module in Doors and i want to get the outlinked requirements so i did that :

```
Stream outfile= write("D:\\Users\\iiii\\" reportName ".txt")
outfile << "Spec Report Requirement IDs\n-----------------------------\n"
Object o
Module m = read(planSpecReportPath_inDoors)
Link outLink
ModName_ parentModName
for o in m do
{
    for outLink in o -> "*" do
    {
        parentModName = target(outLink)
        string h = fullName(parentModName) "\n\n"
        outfile << h 

    }
}
```

however i ONLY get the linked requirement documents paths and can't get exact Req ID .

My question is if i want to get all outlinks to specific Requirement Module with Requirement IDs not just Requirement Document path , what shall i do , any help ?

Answer (score 1):

you will need the perm

```
int targetAbsNo (Link)
```

So, in your example something like

```
parentModName = target(outLink)
int iTarget = targetAbsNo(outLink)
string h = fullName(parentModName) " (" iTarget ")" "\n\n"
```

Comment: it worked ! thanks alot , but do you know how i can get such Doors DXL info beside the pdf ?

Comment: there are perms lists on the internet, e.g. at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014580797